# What is the meaning of error=x509: certificate is valid for user A, not localhost in Docker?

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-compose

I am using a Docker container to run a bunch of services, all of those services make use of certificates to communicate to each other.

When starting up those services there is one in concrete that complains with the following error

```
> discovery_1 | INFO ttn: Got public keys for token validation
> discovery_1 | DEBUG Connected to gRPC server Address=localhost:1900
> discovery_1 | FATAL Could not start client for gRPC proxy error=x509: certificate is valid for discovery, not localhost
> ttnbackbone_discovery_1 exited with code 1
```

I have created the certificate for "discovery" user but still Docker runs it for the localhost, in some way, which I don't understand... I have also followed [this tutorial of certificates usage](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) from Docker but still I have the same error.

What can I do further?

THanks in advance,

REgards!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this today. x509 certificates have a Common Name attribute that some software use to match the DNS hostname of a server. Here was my error with a certificate with CN of `localhost` and a DNS hostname of `docker1-staging`:

```
error during connect: Get https://docker1-staging:2376/v1.26/containers/json: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, not docker1-staging
```

I'll have to regenerate the certificate used by the Docker server and make sure it has a CN value of `docker1-staging`. You'll have to do the same with a CN value of `localhost`.